# Creating Database diagram in visual studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, database-diagram

How do i create a database diagram in MS Visual Studio 2015? There is no option to create one.

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution? trying to find something, but currently without any luck.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Visual Studio 2015 - Sql Server Project Database Diagram](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36655408/visual-studio-2015-sql-server-project-database-diagram)

Answer (score 1):

Add to project ADO.NET Entity Data model. which create `.edmx` file and contains a tables with relation. More info MSDN.

1. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189078.aspx
2. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171978.aspx

It also install Entity framework.

Open Server explorer > Connection to Database. Select Microsoft SQL Server(you must be installed it first ), Server name=.; (or your PC name) and then choose your database schema.

If this is complicated to you,please watch this video :) Good luck

[Visual Studio tutorial: Working with databases in Server](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SrsCz2q2zLo)