# Visual Studio 2015 - Sql Server Project Database Diagram

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

Is there as way to create database diagram in Visual Studio as a Sql Server Project?

I know it is possible to do it in sql server management studio, but I am also  wondering if it is possible to do in Visual studio.

Answer (score 5):

As per MSDN (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y5a4ezk9.aspx) the Visual Database Designer was deprecated in Visual Studio 2013. 
If you're using an older version of Visual Studio, note that support for the design tool within Visual Studio stops at SQL Server 2008 R2. (See "Important" box on top of page at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171976.aspx )

The short answer: no.

Answer (score 2):

Actually there are two ways that i know In Visual Studio.

1. Add to project `ADO.NET Entity Data model`. It creates for you a `.edmx` file which contains a tables with relation.
   More info [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716685%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). It also install Entity framework.
2. Open `Server explorer` > `Connection to Database`. Select Microsoft SQL Server, Server name=`.`; (or your PC name) and then choose your database schema.

   You can check this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SrsCz2q2zLo).

I hope it helps you.

Comment: Choice 1: I knew about ADO.NET but i cant do that in SQL Server project; Choice 2:  I connect to the database but it doesn't show Database Diagrams folder like Sql Server Management Studio. I believe VS2012 shows Database Diagrams folder

Comment: in this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6Suas2O7DZ4) he has a Diagrams folder (VS 2010).
[Another video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aC3ulKUjBW4) shows another way to make diagrams, but i couldn't found a solution for the diagram folders, I have tested in VS 2015